# Rocketchat docker container not starting after reboot

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rocket.chat

I have a couple of running Rocketchat containers running Rocketchat version 4.8.7 without any issues. I run into issues when I update these containers to use Rocketchat version 6.3.10 and above.

When I update the mongo and rocketchat versions, the first time I run `docker compose up -d` the containers boot, Rocketchat successfully connects to mongo and the service is working fine.

However, after restarting the containers with `docker compose down` then `docker compose up -d` the rocketchat container starts but doesn't boot up rocketchat. Below is the log from docker logs command indicating where it hangs. Please note that on the first boot (when it works fine), it still shows the same errors, but after that, it continues with establishing connections and running, but after docker restart it just hangs at this step.

`docker logs rocketchat-1`

```
strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "additionalProperties" at "#" (strictTypes)
strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "properties" at "#" (strictTypes)
strict mode: use allowUnionTypes to allow union type keyword at "#/properties/value" (strictTypes)
(node:1) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.

Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
LocalStore: store created at 
LocalStore: store created at 
LocalStore: store created at 
MessageType.render is deprecated. Use MessageType.message instead. livechat_webrtc_video_call
{"level":40,"time":"2023-11-02T11:36:44.373Z","pid":1,"hostname":"a4b7a47107e9","name":"VoIPService","msg":"Voip is not enabled. Cant start the service"}
```

#### Server Setup Information

- Version of Rocket.Chat Server: 6.3.10
- Operating System: Ubuntu-22
- Deployment Method: docker
- MongoDB Version: 5.0
- Firewalls involved: no

This is the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/RocketChat/Docker.Official.Image/blob/master/compose.yml) file I am using, it is the original file suggested in the [rocketchat instructions](https://docs.rocket.chat/deploy/deploy-rocket.chat/deploy-with-docker-and-docker-compose).

The log after first boot is the following:

```
strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "additionalProperties" at "#" (strictTypes)
strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "properties" at "#" (strictTypes)
strict mode: use allowUnionTypes to allow union type keyword at "#/properties/value" (strictTypes)
(node:1) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.

Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
LocalStore: store created at 
LocalStore: store created at 
LocalStore: store created at 
MessageType.render is deprecated. Use MessageType.message instead. livechat_webrtc_video_call
{"level":40,"time":"2023-11-02T11:33:57.720Z","pid":1,"hostname":"b44e862a023c","name":"VoIPService","msg":"Voip is not enabled. Cant start the service"}
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.818Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/BROKER: Moleculer v0.14.29 is starting...
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.818Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/BROKER: Namespace: <not defined>
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.819Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/BROKER: Node ID: 093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.820Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/REGISTRY: Strategy: RoundRobinStrategy
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.821Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/REGISTRY: Discoverer: LocalDiscoverer
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.822Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/BROKER: Serializer: JSONSerializer
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.834Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/BROKER: Validator: FastestValidator
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.839Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/BROKER: Registered 13 middleware(s).
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.841Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/BROKER: Transporter: TcpTransporter
{"level":51,"time":"2023-11-02T11:34:09.867Z","pid":1,"hostname":"b44e862a023c","name":"DatabaseWatcher","msg":"Using change streams"}
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.959Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/TRANSIT: Connecting to the transporter...
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.968Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/TRANSPORTER: TCP server is listening on port 34383
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.970Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/TRANSPORTER: UDP Discovery is disabled.
[2023-11-02T11:34:09.974Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/TRANSPORTER: TCP Transporter started.
ufs: temp directory created at "/tmp/ufs"
[2023-11-02T11:34:10.501Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/REGISTRY: '$node' service is registered.
[2023-11-02T11:34:10.502Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/REGISTRY: 'matrix' service is registered.
[2023-11-02T11:34:10.503Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/$NODE: Service '$node' started.
[2023-11-02T11:34:10.503Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/MATRIX: Service 'matrix' started.
[2023-11-02T11:34:10.504Z] INFO  093001c1-c943-4fb6-8e9f-3e994cf7e41b/BROKER: ✔ ServiceBroker with 2 service(s) started successfully in 645ms.
(node:1) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: cursor.count is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version, please use `collection.estimatedDocumentCount` or `collection.countDocuments` instead 
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                     SERVER RUNNING                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                        |
|  Rocket.Chat Version: 6.3.10                           |
|       NodeJS Version: 14.21.3 - x64                    |
|      MongoDB Version: 5.0.22                           |
|       MongoDB Engine: wiredTiger                       |
|             Platform: linux                            |
|         Process Port: 3000                             |
|             Site URL: http://myurl.com:4500  |
|     ReplicaSet OpLog: Enabled                          |
|          Commit Hash: 6c79ffc512                       |
|        Commit Branch: HEAD                             |
|                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

However after reboot it hangs on the VOIP message.